# boost::gregorian::date from std::string

Tags: c++, boost-date-time

I tried to convert std::string into boost::gregorian::date in this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::string s_date = "1922-02-29";
  std::stringstream ss(s_date);
  boost::gregorian::date_input_facet *df = new boost::gregorian::date_input_facet("%Y-%m-%d");
  ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), df));
  date d;
  ss>>d;
  std::cout<<d<<std::endl;
}
```

But unfortunately I only received "not-a-date-time". What am I doing so wrong? Is there any easier way to convert string in such a popular form to boost::gregorian:date?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What am I doing so wrong?

You get "not-a-date-time" because that is not a valid date: 1922 wasn't a leap year, so there were only 28 days in February.

Your code works as expected for me if I change it to a valid date such as `1922-02-28` or `1924-02-29`.

> Is there any easier way to convert string in such a popular form to boost::gregorian:date?

```
boost::gregorian::date d = boost::gregorian::from_string(s_date);
```

Comment: Obvious answer. I've got a malformed date from a file and do not event thought that problem could be related to something else then my code. And I suppose you had the boost::gregorian::from_string on mind.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
boost::gregorian::date d = boost::gregorian::from_undelimited_string(s_date);
```

Not 'from_date'

The string is required to take for form YYYYMMDD.

Or you can use:

```
boost::gregorian::date d = boost::gregorian::from_string(s_date);
```

where your string takes the form YYYY/MM/DD